# count string occurrences using map

Tags: javascript, prototype

For a little example program I needed to count occurrences of multiple strings.
So I used a map to count using a string as key a number as value. For this I added a function to the Map Object:

```
Map.prototype.inc = function(s) {
     if (this.has(s))  this[s] = this[s]+1 
     else              this[s] = 1
}
```

This doesn't work as intended. This input:

```
var test = new Map()
test.inc("a"); test.inc("a"); test.inc("b");
```

results in:

> test = {"a":1, "b":1}

The desired result is :

> {"a":2, "b":1}

if the key didn't exist its set to 1. Okay  
if the key did exist its value remains 1. Bad

After debugging I found that the this pointer is always an empty map.

So I did read about the *this* keyword that did't explain anything (to me) actually. *this* should be the map right?

Why isn't this working?

It's pretty easy code I know that's why I want to know how it works.

I hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `set` and `get` methods like this.

```js
    Map.prototype.inc = function(s) {
         if (this.has(s)) {
           this.set(s, this.get(s) + 1);      
         } else {
           this.set(s, 1);
         }
    }

    var t = new Map();
    t.inc('a');t.inc('a');t.inc('b');
    console.log(t);
```